# QUERYSET: How can I filter by field in a list (case insensitive)

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I want to filter field using __in but i also want it to be case insensitive when i pass it to the query

This is something Ive tried:

```
fields = ['Banana','Water Melon','grapes']

MyModel.objects.filter(field__in__icontains=fields).values()
```

and returned an error (of course).

> Unsupported lookup 'in' for CharField or join on the field not
>   permitted, perhaps you meant in?

I want it to be something like that. Any help/enlightenment would be appreciated,

Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: you can use iexact

Comment: But how do i filter a list?

Comment: django orm does't support that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Django ORM supports something like that, but a hack could work using UNION.

Haven't tested it but try storm the brain by doing something similar to this:

```
fruits = ['Banana', 'mango', 'Ginger']
queryset = Fruit.objects.all()
for fruit in fruits:
    queryset = queryset.union(Fruit.objects.filter(name__icontains=fruit)
```